# Linq-to-SQL Parent Link Removal Slow

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

We have a table with a self-link and some rows need to be deleted. I'm removing the link before deleting rows, but it is very very slow. Since thousands of rows need to be removed, I need a faster way.

I've tried moving SubmitChanges outside the loop but it's no quicker. I've verified that the query to retrieve rows for deletion is not the problem.

```
public void ClearOldRunStops()
{
    List<RunStop> runStops = db.RunStops.Where(a => a.shiftstarttime < DateFunctions.UtcNow().AddDays(-15) && a.status == RunStopStatus.Deleted.ToString()).ToList();

    for (int counter = 0; counter < runStops.Count; counter++)
    {
        //remove any RunStop self-links before row deletion
        for (int counter2 = 0; counter2 < runStops[counter].RunStops.Count; counter2++)
            runStops[counter].RunStops[counter2].runstopid = null;

        db.RunStops.DeleteOnSubmit(runStops[counter]);

        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you select all the entities which need to be deleted and then use `DeleteAllOnSubmit`? This approach should be much faster.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Kirill. I tried it, but performance did not improve. It seems that the slow step is the removal of the parent link.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in the end, an index was required on runstopid, otherwise it does a table scan for each parent link removal.